# Problema con funcion simplexml_load_file laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hola tengo el siguiente problema con la función simplexml_load_file() al intentar acceder a la siguiente ruta /uploads/bacapp-s-a-c-/2022/6/FACTURAE001-221620602021107.XML

Me sale el siguiente warning:

simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "public/uploads/bacapp-s-a-c-/2022/6/FACTURAE001-221620602021107.XML"

aca estaria el codigo que estoy utilizando para esto

```
$rut =  simplexml_load_file($Adj->Adjunto);   
dd($rut);
```

La variable ($Adj->Adjunto) me trae la ruta donde esta el archivo por cada item y posteriormente la recorro con un un foreach... para imprimir los datos que necesito...

Gracias a quien pueda ayudarme

Comment: ¿Si cambias el `$Adj->Adjunto`por `/uploads/bacapp-s-a-c-/2022/6/FACTURAE001-221620602021107.XML` directamente te funciona bien?

Comment: Hola, @masterguru gracias por tomarte el tiempo de escribir... y no sale lo mismo...

Comment: pues primero deberias conseguirlo con la ruta hardcodeada, y luego corregir la variable esa para que funcione bien.  Si con la ruta hardcodeada no te funciona entonces mal vamos y no sabremos como ayudarte.

Comment: ojo la ruta esta bien porque de por si puedo dscargar el archivo directamente de esa ruta... pero por alguna razon la función no funcina... al tener esta ruta... no obstante esta en un servidor

Comment: Pues prueba poniendo la ruta completa que ves en la url cuando lo abres directamente, es decir, `http://midominio.com/uploads/bacapp-s-a-c-/2022/6/FACTURAE001-221620602021107.XML`

Comment: @masterguru muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo para ayudarme ahora me sale el siguiente warning simplexml_load_file ( Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found )

Comment: Bueno, debes adaptar la ruta a tu dominio, lo mio era un ejemplo. Antes has dicho que el archivo existe porque eres capaz de descargarlo directamente (entiendo que con el navegador), pues esa ruta es la que debes poner en lugar de la mia de ejemplo.

Comment: si claro eso hice coloque la ruta asi como me indicaste obviamente con el dominio... y ahora me sale eso.  Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found, pero alli esta

Comment: Pues es un misterio para mi, la verdad, si con esa ruta eres capaz de descargarlo pero en cambio la funcion te dice que no lo encuentra no se que podria ser, como no sea alguna limitación de acceso a urls, pero lo dudo, o quizas es que tu ruta es con https y en mi ejemplo te lo puse con http a secas

Comment: si mi ruta es con https y lo he colocado de igual manera https y ahora me sale el siguiente warning ( Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found )

Comment: Bueno, pues no avanzamos, un error 404 es que no encuentra la URL o ésta no es válida.  Lo siento, aquí me estanco y no se por donde seguir, no tiene sentido para mi.

Comment: @masterguru muchas gracias de igual forma por intentarme ayudar

Comment: Suerte!  Algo se nos escapa seguro, pero a ciegas no se por donde seguir, lo siento.

Comment: Hola que tal @masterguru ya lo he logrado solucionar dejare la respuesta por aca de igual forma por si alguien tiene el mismo problema... en algun momento ya que estuve 2 dias en esto... de igual forma te comento que me diste una idea y de esa idea llegue a la solucion muchisimas gracias nuevamente

Comment: perfecto, me alegro haberte podido ayudar, aunque viendo tu respuesta **jamas** se me hubiera ocurrido eso a mi :-D  (más que nada porque no uso laravel, solo se de PHP puro).  Saludos!

Comment: @masterguru bueno si tienes alguna duda o algo respecto a laravel aca estare si me necesitas no soy experto pero quizas pueda apoyarte en algo gracias nuevamente por brindarme tus conocimientos hasta un nuevo problema o bugg jajaja :D

Answer (score 1):

Actualizacion a simplexml_load_file()

despues de estar un rato la manera correcta para cargar un archivo desde donde lo guardas seria de esta manera

```
$rutas = Storage::path($Adj->Adjunto);
$xml = simplexml_load_file($rutas);             
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('cbc', 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2');
          $xml->registerXPathNamespace('cac', 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2');
          foreach($xml->xpath('//cac:Price') as $PartyName){ 
            echo (string) $PartyName->xpath('//cbc:RegistrationName')[1];
    
        }
```

que storage::path hace la función para poder buscar el archivo directamente en la en la carpeta donde este ubicado el archivo que deseas y posteriormente alli podras manipularlo en mi caso era para manipular un xml ($Adj->Adjunto) esta variable me trae la ubicación del archivo desde la db y con el "Storage::path" accedes a el sin problemas  espero poder ayudar a alguien con esta respuesta en algun futuro